# App Engine Not sending mails

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have the following code for sending mail, but it is not working for some days i have being trying. I have followed all possible descriptions of how this is done and no way still. I am using the javax mail service to send the mail, i have also updated all dependencies but the logs will show that message function was called but i will not recieve any mail.

```
import com.dotdex.squattn.models.UserMail;
import com.dotdex.squattn.util.Utility;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


/**
 * An endpoint class we are exposing
 */
@Api(
        name = "userMailApi",
        version = "v1",
        resource = "userMail",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "squattn.dotdex.com",
                ownerName = "squattn.dotdex.com",
                packagePath = ""
        )
)
public class UserMailEndpoint {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserMailEndpoint.class.getName());

    /**
     * This inserts a new <code>UserMail</code> object.
     *
     * @param userMail The object to be added.
     * @return The object to be added.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "sendUserConfirmationMail")
    public UserMail sendUserConfirmationMail(UserMail userMail) {
        logger.info("Calling insertUserMail method");
        if(sendMail(userMail))
        {
            userMail.setMailSent(true);
        }

        return userMail;
    }

    private boolean sendMail(UserMail userMail) {
        //start sending the mail
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        String link = "<br><br><a href='" +Utility.APP_URL + "/verifyEmail?uid=" + userMail.getUserId() + "' style='color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: baseline; border: 4px solid #6fb3e0; padding: 4px 9px; font-size: 15px; line-height: 21px; background-color: #6fb3e0;'>&nbsp; Confirm &nbsp;</a>";

        try {

            Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
            MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            htmlPart.setContent(Utility.TOP_HTML + link + Utility.BOTTOM_HTML, "text/html");
            mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("noreply@parkpal-1278.appspotmail.com","ParkPal App"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress("jerryhanksokafor@gmail.com", userMail.getUserName()));
            msg.setSubject("Verify Your Email.");
            msg.setContent(mp);
            Transport.send(msg);
            new Firebase(Utility.APP_URL).child(Utility.USER_STRING).child(userMail.getUserId()).child("verifyMailSent").setValue(true);
            return true;
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // ...
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // ...
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify the dev server will never send emails like this. You'll see a log message on the dev server console instead. Please try to log the exceptions and edit your question to include the error message. You may also want to activate bounce messages in appengine and handle them so you can exclude mail delivery issues.

Comment: Also check if you're not hitting this GAE issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12786